# Using multiple PostgeSQL servers with a single shared network data directory?

Tags: postgresql

How does PostgreSQL handle running multiple servers on different machines using a shared data directory? Does it automatically handle this under-the-hood without problems? Is it possible, but requiring some special configuration? Or is this a bad idea in general?

I'm doing some data science on high performance machine cluster, where I submit jobs, the job is run by a random machine, and each machine has access to a shared network drive. Currently, I'm using SQLite, where this use-case works fine. A single shared SQLite database file can handle multiple connections from different machines without trouble.

I'm now attempting to switch over to PostgreSQL. Intercommunication between the machines of the cluster is surprisingly not straightforward. So while the immediate solution should be having one server which all the other machines connect to, this might not end up being practical. Ideally, I could just continue doing what I've been doing with the SQLite setup. That is, have each machine run it's own PostgreSQL server, which then connects to the shared databases.

Comment: "*handle running multiple servers on different machines using a shared data directory*" - it doesn't. That will simply corrupt your database. Do not do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, no, no and yes.

A PostgreSQL installation ("cluster" is the term used in the manuals) expects to be in charge of all of its files. It carefully coordinates access between multiple processes accessing those files. You are supposed to access PostgreSQL in a client/server manner over a socket (unix if local, tcp if not).

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported with PostgreSQL.  It will lead to corruption and data loss.  If you can't simplify your networking, then you best stick to SQLite.  (Assuming it is actually safe with SQLite, something I haven't verified)